# High Contrast hides Menu Item Text

Tags: windows, winforms

Windows 10 - High Contrast - MenuStrip control. When NOT moused over the text of the menu item is hidden. Is this by design? If not, is there a fix?

Comment: What Framework version are you targeting?

Comment: I confess again (not my original code) I am targeting .NET Core 3.1 - the problem was a stray piece of code changing the background to Black. I translated this form from VB.NET to C# using the icsharpcode CodeConverter and it broke up the form from the designer in a little different way. I had deleted some crazy code before I translated that I now realize changed the color away from Black. I am convinced that monkeys coded this application - but how did they get the typewriters to fit in the floppy slot?